# Boostrap 4 grid re-order

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have the following HTML code using Bootstrap 4:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12 col-sm-4">
    First, but unordered
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 col-sm-4">
    Second, but unordered
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 col-sm-4 order-sm-1">
    Third, but first
  </div>
</div>
```

I am expecting the third `div` to be placed in first position on `sm` screens but it is not. Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/TheRealPapa/4kufr9ue/1/) What have I missed? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order class is not really handeling the order of the elements it's instead like a swap system. So you need to declare an order in other divs too

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12 col-sm-4 order-sm-12">
    First, but unordered
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 col-sm-4 order-sm-12">
    Second, but unordered
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 col-sm-4 order-sm-1">
    Third, but first
  </div>
</div>
```

[Here's a Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4kufr9ue/4/)

Comment: Thanks! That got some action taking place! Now to figure out why it is working upside down to what I want! Mobile first design I guess.

Comment: Maybe because you're using the small devices size https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_small.asp

Comment: It's not a swap system. It's just that default value of `order` attribute in CSS is `0`. Using any class that sets it to any positive value will make that column become last if the siblings don't have a declared `order`.

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr:

Change your markup to:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-4">
      First, but unordered
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-4">
      Second, but unordered
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-4 order-first order-md-0">
      Third, but first
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

## the details

`.order-sm-1` will place `order: 1` on the element, according to lines `#53-#55` in `_grid-framework.scss`:

```css
@for $i from 0 through $columns {
  .order#{$infix}-#{$i} { order: $i; }
}
```

But placing `order: 1` on one column without the rest having an `order` will send that column at the end of the stack, because the default value of `order` is `0`. Any following siblings without an `order` will be placed before your column.

In the same file, at line `#49`, we find `.order#{$infix}-first` (which sets `order:-1`). This will place a column before the rest, as well as `.order#{$infix}-last` will place it after all the rest.

---

To sum up:

- use `.order-sm-last` and `.order-sm-first` to make a column go to front or back of the stack
- use `.order-sm-#{n}` to give it an `order` but also set the `order` on siblings (`order-sm-1` will make a column first if you place `order-sm-2` (or higher - up to 12) on the other columns).

Note they only defined 12 levels for `order`, `.order-sm-13` won't work, unless you define it yourself.

As a final note: if you want your column ordered on `sm` **and below**, your should replace `order-sm-1` with `order-first order-md-0`. `.order-first` makes it first on all intervals and `.order-md-0` sets its `order` back to `0` on `md` and above, so it keeps its place in the layout:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-4">
      First, but unordered
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-4">
      Second, but unordered
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-4 order-first order-md-0">
      Third, but first
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But this is their GA code. Surely I have got it wrong? It is designed mobile first I understand so maybe I have screwed up the HTML?

Comment: Actually, I just looked for a bit in their SASS and i'll update my answer. :)

Comment: @TheRealPapa, I looked into and explained in detail what their SCSS gets translated to, if you're interested.

Answer (score 1):

**EDITED**

I am changing the code in order to adapt it for bootstrap 4 after user comment of @Andrei Gheorghiu

you can use the class order-sm-first which sets the to `order=-1`, with this code the **third** div will be displayed as first for screens that are sm or larger meaning **larger than 576px**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12 col-sm-4">
    First, but unordered
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 col-sm-4">
    Second, but unordered
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 col-sm-4 order-sm-first">
    Third, but first
  </div>
</div>
```

here you can see the forked version of you [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w3narjst/4/)

Comment: `order-sm-unordered` does not exist in Bootstrap v4. And `order` does have a default value. It's `0`.

Comment: you are right, but i noticed that in documentation there is no reference about order-first which sets the `order` to `-1`, with that order value you do not need to specify an order to other divs